# How to encourage undefined behavior / out-of-order execution in C programs?

Tags: c, global-variables, undefined-behavior, unspecified-behavior

I am reading the following article about sequence points in C: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sequence-points-in-c-set-1/

In it, there are several examples of undefined behavior, such as expressions that call two functions that modify a single global variable, or a single expression that increments the same variable more than once.

In theory, I understand the concept.  However, no matter how many times I try to run the examples, the behavior is the same, and never "surprising."

For the purpose of getting a hands-on appreciation of undefined behavior, what's the easiest way to get the examples to be "surprising"?

(If it matters, I am using MINGW64.)

Comment: "However, no matter how many times I try to run the examples, the behavior is the same, and never "surprising." Looks like a perfect case of "undefined."

Comment: Use different compiler options or a different compiler, to make the compiler generate different assembly code.

Comment: @KamilCuk - I am using gcc 8.2.1 on MSYS2 / MINGW64.  What do you suggest I try?

Comment: I suggest you try a different compiler or a different set of compiler options. Then if both compilers generate different assembly code in case of undefined behavior you will get "suprising" behvavior for the same code.

Comment: 'the behavior is the same' because you are using the same compiler which compiles your source using the same algorithm, same optimization options etc. Would be rather hard to be a programmer if compilers would generate different code each time they compile ;-). Use different compilers, different setting and you might see differences but it it not guaranteed.

Comment: The first point you miss is that the undefined behavior is just "**undefined**". Even if the code behaves as you intended, it must be considered  a **casualty**. The software, by definition, act same way each run (algorithm driven behavior), so using the same compiler will give same result (as @Artur said before), while with different compilers or environments the results could be quite different. The second point is that one of the C language aims is to be **portable**, meaning that the same code compiled on a as many different machines, compilers and environments will produce same result. ..

Comment: Continuing. When the same resulte cannot be achieved or, better, guarantee, by the language semantic we say that the behavior is **undefined**. In this case each compiler can produce code that behaves as it wants.

Comment: @anon. I voted up because now, I understand problem I had.

Comment: @Frankie_C: The fact that the Standard does not *mandate* that implementations define a behavior in no way implies any judgment as to whether many or most implementations should define the behavior themselves *anyway*.  The authors of the Standard expected that compiler writers would try to serve the needs of their customers whether or not the Standard required them to do so, and intended that UB be interpreted as an invitation to serve customer needs, not ignore them.

Comment: @Frankie_C: Further, there are trade-offs between making a *language* portable, versus allowing programs written in the language to be portable.  C favors the former; Java the latter.  The thing that made C uniquely useful for many purposes is that implementations intended for low-level programming would process many actions where the Standard imposed no requirements "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment", and programs targeting a particular environment could exploit this with any low-level compiler targeting that environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the best I can come up with at short notice:

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int undefined(int *a, short *b)
{
    *a = 1;
    b[0] = 0;
    b[1] = 0;
    return *a;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    short *y = (short*) &x;
    int z = undefined(&x, y);
    printf("%d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Resulting assembly using gcc 8.3 -O3

```
undefined(int*, short*):
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
    mov     eax, 1
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 0
    ret
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
main:
    sub     rsp, 8
    mov     esi, 1
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 8
    ret
```

See it in action: https://godbolt.org/z/E0XDYt

In particular, it relies on the undefined behavior caused by casting the address of an `int` to a `short*`, an action that breaks the strict aliasing rule, and therefore causes undefined behavior.

Start with the assembly of `undefined()`.  That assumes that since `a` and `b` are different types, they cannot overlap, therefore it optimizes the `return *a;` into `mov eax,1`, even though it would actually return zero if it fetched the value from memory.  Which it does with optimization off, so this is one of those really insidious problems that only manifests in an optimized release build, and not when you try and debug it with a non-optimized debug build.

However, note how the code in `main()` does try and get it right: it inlines, and then optimizes away the call to `undefined()` and instead assumes `0` in `z` when it does the `xor eax,eax` just above the call to `printf`.  So it's ignoring what it just figured out as the return value a few lines above, and is instead using a different value.

All in all, a very badly broken program.  Exactly what you risk with undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A useful pattern when testing gcc and clang is to access arrays using subscripts whose values would be in bounds, but are not known to the compiler, and use the pointer syntax which the Standard describes as equivalent to subscript notation.  Testing gcc and clang with something like:

```
struct S1 {int x;};
struct S2 {int x;};

union foo { struct S1 arr1[8]; struct S2 arr2[8]; } u;

uint32_t test1(int i, int j)
{
  if (sizeof u.arr1 != sizeof u.arr2)
    return -99;
  if (u.arr1[i].x)
    u.arr2[j].x = 2;
  return u.arr1[i].x;
}
uint32_t test2(int i, int j)
{
  if (sizeof u.arr1 != sizeof u.arr2)
    return -99;
  if ((u.arr1+i)->x)
    (u.arr2+j)->x = 2;
  return (u.arr1+i)->x;
}
```

will reveal that although the Standard defines the behavior of `u.arr1[i].x` and `u.arr2[j].x` as equivalent to `(u.arr1+i)->x` and `(u.arr2+j)->x`, respectively, gcc and clang miss an allowable optimization opportunity when given the former that they exploit when given the latter.  Most likely this is because the authors recognize that exploiting the former opportunity would be permissible but would be so undeniably silly that as to compel recognition that the Standard was never intended to encourage all the optimizations it allows.